# Renaming multiple files with same name

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I have a question regarding changing names of multiple files (approximately 800) to fit specific name format.

Exemplary data:

```
- 123_12345_abc455.jpg
- 123_12345_abc677.jpg
- 123_12345_abc899.jpg
- 123_47847_qwe334.jpg
- 123_47847_qwe433.jpg
- 123_54321_uwu123.jpg
```

Objective:

```
- 12345_1.jpg
- 12345_2.jpg
- 12345_3.jpg
- 47847_1.jpg
- 47847_2.jpg
- 54321_1.jpg
```

Note that after we remove characters from start and end we are left with multiple files of the same name, which causes errors and script simply omits those files with same name.

What I've got so far is:

`ls | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name.substring(0,$_.BaseName.length-7) + $_.Extension}`

Comment: You're objective is to remove 5 out of 6 files and rename the remaining file to something... simpler?

Comment: I've edited my post so it's clearer. I do not wish to remove any files - simply rename them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one technique:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\*.jpg |
    Group-Object {$_.Name.Split('_')[1]} |
        ForEach-Object {
            $namePart = $_.Name
            $_.Group | 
                ForEach-Object {$i=1}{
                    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ("$namePart`_" + $i++ + $_.Extension)
                }
        }
```

Comment: Seems a good approach, with minimal I/O induced. However, regarding reusability in case of crash/powerdown/etc., it could be useful to also include an `$i` initialization for the last index of potential preexisting "already renamed" files in the path ?

Comment: @Zilog80 Yeah, this isn't a fully robust solution for all situations, just an example to show one way to approach the problem.  It's left as an exercise for the reader to add better error handling, etc. :-)

Comment: An absolute legend, lad! Thank you so much. Works wonders. All best to you my friend =)